# file_exist error? File doesn't exist

Tags: php

```
<input type = "file" name = "mImage[]">
<input type = "file" name = "mImage[]">
<input type = "file" name = "mImage[]">
<input type = "file" name = "mImage[]">

if($_FILES['mImage']['size'] == 0){ echo "File not uploaded"}
if(file_exist($dir . $_FILES['mImage']['name'])){ echo "File already exist"}
```

I'm able to upload four images, but pretending to be the user to upload a file the second, but want to upload one, my code echos out `"File already exist"`. I've used the `file_exist` function. My assumption for my code assuming the file already exist with only uploading one file the second time (and the one file doesn't exist in the directory), is it thinks the `$_FILES['mImage']['name'] = "."` or `".."` . If that is the case, then I can implement a code to ignore `"."` or `".."` . I need assistance as why my code thinks the file already exist when I upload one file the second time.

Answer (score 1):

Since your file inputs use an array, $_FILES['mImage'] will be an array of files. 
Try this:

```
if($_FILES['mImage'][0]['size'] == 0){ echo "File not uploaded"}
if(file_exist($dir . $_FILES['mImage'][0]['name'])){ echo "File already exist"}
```

You'll have to repeat this for each file or iterate through $_FILES['mImage'] with a loop like foreach.

Comment: I iterated through my code. My apologies for not putting the iteration in the code above. I want to allow user to upload any amount of images no greater than four. If the user wants to upload 1, 2, 3, or 4, but when I upload one the second time around (uploaded four the first time), I get "File already exist".

Comment: I could use count to check such as:

    $count = 0;
    //iterate
    if($_FILES['mImage']['size'][$i] == 4){
    $count++;

     if($count == 0){
     echo "No files has been uploaded";
     return; //stops there
    }

I want user to be able to upload any amount of images, as long as 1>= x (amount of images uploaded at once) <= 4 is true.

Comment: Correction: I could use count to check such as:

    $count = 0;
    //iterate
    if($_FILES['mImage']['size'][$i] == 0){
    $count++;

     if($count == 4){
     echo "No files has been uploaded";
     return; //stops there
    }

I want user to be able to upload any amount of images, as long as 1>= x (amount of images uploaded at once) <= 4 is true.

Comment: It would have to be $_FILES['mImage'][$i]['size'], not $_FILES['mImage']['size'][$i]

Comment: $_FILES['mImage'][$i]['size'] isn't not working. I have this weekend to figure it out. Thanks for your assistance by the way.

Comment: Have you set the form attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"? And have you checked that the limits set in your php.ini aren't exceeded (maximum amount of upload files and file sizes)?

Comment: Yes I've set the enctype="multipart/form-data" and made sure the files hasn't exceeded in php.ini